# Android : EditText with custom keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I created my own custom keyboard following the the example in the sdk.

Now I would like to use this custom keyboard by default on my EditText in my app (actualy I have to long press the edittext and then choose my `custom keyboard`).

How can I do that ? (seems to be related to the inputType property but I can't find out how to set it)

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do that?

Have your users set your keyboard to be their default. Applications do not have control over that.

Comment: @commonsware....I want to access a keyboard via Bluetooth.

For example : Two devices connect each other via Bluetooth if I open keyboard in the first device, and I want access that keyboard in another device in any edittext.

So how can I access that keyboard in another device via bluetooth in android?

Answer (score 2):

If by saying "I created my own custom keyboard" you mean you wrote your own IME, this is probably not what you want.  An IME is a separate component that is designed to interact with any other application on the device for text input.

If you just want a custom keyboard in your own app, you should implement that inside your app as part of its UI.

Comment: Ok  thanks ! Yes I made my own IME, but as you say, I want it to be usable only inside my app.
What component should I use to implement this in my app ? Do you have a link ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `PopupWindow` containing the layout of your custom keyboard, position the popup Window at bottom of the screen  and handle clicks of the custom keyboard buttons yourself. Do disable the virtual keyboard before you do that.

For example of popup window, you can check:
http://al1us.net/?p=131

use  `GRAVITY.BOTTOM` in `showAtLocation()` function