# Dynamically changing onscreen keyboard layout in android

Tags: android

I would like to build a custom keyboard layout for a messenger app I am working on which is localized within the app. I currently noticed that keyboard settings could be selected from the settings to displayed preferred layout choice e.g english,chinese, french. 
My goal is to (1) Dynamically assign keyboard layout from within the app on specifying what language you would want to send the message as
(2) Build 3 different keyboard layouts that are not included as the default locales of the device and be able to do as SAID IN 1 above.

Ps, How can I dynamically change onscreen keyboard to display in different language formats AND how can i build a custom keyboard layout to allow users insert text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : EditText with custom keyboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797958/android-edittext-with-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really include a true custom "keyboard" within your own application. See here: [Android : EditText with custom keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797958/android-edittext-with-custom-keyboard).

The only thing you can do besides getting your users to set your keyboard up in the settings is build your custom keyboard as a view and handle all of its events(key presses, open/close, etc..) yourself from your activity. You'll also have to manually hook it up to put the text into your edit texts. You'd have to put in a considerable amount of work to actually make it feel to the user like a keyboard.